# Can I hook up an ice maker with a 1/4" plastic pipe to my garden hose faucet easily?

Tags: plumbing

Just got my hubby a new ice maker and it has a 1/4" water line.  Thing is it is going in the garage and needs to run off of the garden hose faucet.   Is there an adapter that I can use to run the hose faucet to the ice maker?   Do I need to install any copper tubing?

Thank you!

Barbara

Comment: Are the pipes exposed the feed the garage sink or other faucet? like the laundry tub? A sanitary tap will work then

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done.  It make take more than one adapter in sequence to get from the 3/4" hose connection to the 1/4" plastic tube.  Any plumbing department in a decent hardware or home-improvement store will likely have them.

The hose connector threads are different from standard American "NPT" pipe threads.  You'll need to go from the 3/4" hose thread on the faucet, to 3/4" NPT thread, and from there it may take one or more reducers to get down to a 1/4" compression fitting that the ice maker wants.

Alternatively, there may also be some adapters in the irrigation and sprinkler pipe section, that can go from the 3/4" hose connector to 1/4" tubing using barbed push-on connectors.  Something used for drip-irrigation for plants may have the right sizes.